# Changing a while loop so echo doesn't print more than once

Tags: php

I've got some code that echo's a line of text inside a while loop. But I don't want it as a loop and can't seem to get it to work without the while(). My code is below - how can I get the echo to only print once?

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  do($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $unco and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is in Garage<br />";
}
  do($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is being serviced<br />";
}
  do($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $comp) {
    echo "Vehicle is ready for collection<br />";
}
}
```

UPDATE: using if

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {   
}

if($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $unco and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is in Garage";
} 
  if($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
    echo "Vehicle is being serviced";
}
  if($row['InGarage'] == $comp and $row['BeingServiced'] == $comp and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $comp) {
    echo "Vehicle is ready for collection";
}
```

Comment: Aside from being very rude, Marc is right. This can be achieved by doing and if statement.

Comment: When I use an if statement, nothing prints, where as with the loop, it prints loads of times... I'll put my new code in the body of the question

Comment: `When I use an if statement, nothing prints `; Because you put everything outside your loop body :)

Comment: In your updated code, you closed your loop before you even got to your `if()` statements.

Comment: @the_pete I don't want it looped, that is my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `do` operators are not required, but the `while` is needed to iterate through all the results from the database. Instead of using `do`, it would be more sensible to use `if`. You can also refactor your conditions to create slightly shorter conditions:

```
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['InGarage'] == $comp) {
        if ($row['BeingServiced'] == $comp) {
            if ($row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
                echo "Vehicle is being serviced<br />";
            }
            elseif ($row['ReadyForCollection'] == $comp) {
                echo "Vehicle is ready for collection<br />";
            }
        }
        elseif ($row['BeingServiced'] == $unco and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
            echo "Vehicle is in Garage<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Refactoring your conditions will save your script from having to make extra comparisons. In your original script, you test `$row['InGarage'] == $comp` each time:

```
if($row['InGarage'] == $comp and ... ) {
    echo "Vehicle is in Garage";
}
elseif($row['InGarage'] == $comp and ... ) {
    echo "Vehicle is being serviced";
}
elseif($row['InGarage'] == $comp and ... ) {
    echo "Vehicle is ready for collection";
}
```

It's more efficient to test it once and then test the other conditions:

```
if($row['InGarage'] == $comp) {
    if ($row['BeingServiced'] == $unco and $row['ReadyForCollection'] == $unco) {
        (etc.)
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer nesting as it makes the code easier and clearer (for me) to read. If you like long lines, go for the other method. Additionally, the original code tests the first condition, `$row['InGarage'] == $comp`, on each `if`. It only needs to be tested once.

Comment: It still echo's nothing... I set up an echo to make sure the connection is established which it is

Comment: @ialarmedalien How am I able to add another if statement that echo's another line when the SQLSRV row isn't found? I've tried but haven't succeeded

Comment: You can nest the whole thing in an 'if-else' loop -- `if($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) { ...code to iterate through rows... } else { echo "No data retrieved from the database!"; }`. Do you do any error checking before this code to make sure that the connection occurred OK?

Comment: Yeah I've got an echo to print when the Connection is established. It works fine now!

Comment: Excellent! Next step: world domination! ;^)